# Moving Object with Keys Leaves a Trail

Tags: java, image, swing

In my Java game, I have a player class which has a BufferedImage assigned to it from a sprite sheet. I've just added in KeyAdapters and KeyListeners which just move the player around the screen. However, when I do this, it leaves behind a trail of the image.

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    p.render(g); //p is the player object

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);

    frame.add(game);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();

}
```

Comment: We still need to see where you're doing your actual drawing. Your problem has *nothing* to do with the KeyListener and all to do with your drawing.

Comment: Look at the render method in the player class.

Comment: @sparklyllama: The render method doesn't show how you're doing your drawing. Again, if you need help, show your drawing code. Not sure how to convince you do to this. Please help me here. Where do you call `render(...)`? How do you get your Graphics object? Where's your `paintComponent(...)` override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issue might be that you have a background that seems like it keeps the last drawn things in it.

So I think that you need to re-paint the background when you move the image.

Here is a [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/) to Graphics basics in Java with simple examples